# C++ Making form clickable when game

Tags: c++, forms, hook, direct3d, clickable

I want to make an app to see some values on game, I wrote some codes, but I need to click the form when the game is open.

When I click to form, the game minimized, and returns me to desktop. How can I do that, I am new on this site, and I'm Turkish maybe you cannot understand my English.

Comment: I found that remote debugging was a good way around this issue.

Comment: Game UI's are usually rendered on the game rendering surface and not Dialogs/Windows so you don't lose game focus.